# MySql reserve specific index on sorting (Fix an order for few rows to override existing sorting)

Tags: mysql, database-administration

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2022-5-4 |
| B | 2022-6-21 |
| C | 2022-6-22 |
| D | 2022-7-2 |

In above table sorting is according to Date column, now I just moved last D record on 3rd position by using drag-drop. Here requirement is record D always remain on 3rd index however rest of the sorting will be according to Date in ascending order

Comment: Not possible in a table. Tables are not sorted, if you want to see data sorted the you have to query the data with a ORDER BY

Comment: Or do you mean this is the result of a query, if so, please show us the query

Comment: I just want to reserve few indexes, for example I just added priority for 2 records like these records always be on 4th and 6th position and rest of the sorting will be order by Date ASC

Comment: Again are you talking about doing this in the table OR as part of a query of the table??

Comment: I want to do this in MySql query where I am ready to insert new column where I can save position of row.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are unordered sets of rows. The rows in a table have no natural order. It may look like they do because you often get the rows in the same order when you do `SELECT * FROM tbl`. But that is deceptive. Without ORDER BY, the order of rows is unpredictable.

If you want your rows to appear in a particular order you need a column to control that. Rigging up a table for drag-and-drop reordering isn't simple.